# .NET web form drop down list resets on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've searched through a heap of similar questions and done a bit of googling but I cannot find the answer to my problem...

I would like to have a drop down list that is populated by categories in a database...upon selecting a category and hitting submit, a gridview is populated with all the items in that category.

Now, everything works, except whenever I select anything in the category drop down box, it resets straight away to the first selection. So I'm unable to submit any value other than the first to the gridview.  I am using autopostback on this item. I have tried to use appenddatabounditems too but that just populated the list with more and more of the same entries...

I would love if anyone could tell me how I can just get the dropdownlist to hold its position after postback?

```
Selected Category:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="buttonCategorySubmit" runat="server" OnClick="buttonCategorySubmit_Click" Text="Submit" />
    <br />

</div>
    <asp:GridView ID="CategoryGridView" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
    <br />

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateCategorySelection();
    }

    public void PopulateCategorySelection()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnString"]);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AllCategories", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ddlCategory.DataSource = ddlValues;
        ddlCategory.DataValueField = "CategoryID";
        ddlCategory.DataTextField = "Title";
        ddlCategory.DataBind();

        conn.Close();


    }

    protected void buttonCategorySubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateCategoryTable();
    }

    public void PopulateCategoryTable()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Connstring"]);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectCategory", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Selected", ddlCategory.SelectedItem.Value);

        conn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();
        CategoryGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        CategoryGridView.DataBind();

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I literally just worked it out everyone...For anyone that has the same issue, you need to check in the page_load method whether the page is loading because a new page is being generated, or information is just being posted-back for the user. If its just postback, we dont want to populate the category dropdown box again.  So we use the IsPostBack object in the page_load method, like this:

```
 if (!IsPostBack) 
        {
            PopulateCategorySelection();
        }
```